# Vscode flutter android emulator running problem

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, gradle

i used same emulator on android studio without any problem but when i tried to `flutter run` on vscode i got this problem. `flutter doctor` and `flutter doctor -v` result perfectly fine

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'D:\Flutter_kurs\flutter_full_learn\android\settings.gradle' line: 21

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader', version: '1.0.0']
> Could not find implementation class 'FlutterAppPluginLoaderPlugin' for plugin 'dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader' specified in jar:file:/C:/Users/berat/.gradle/caches/jars-9/91e536670c936165e16e377399c49e69/gradle-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/gradle-plugins/dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader.properties.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 793ms
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution, just change gradle/wrapper -> gradle-wrapper.properties distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-all.zip